# Use PDF as an image Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, assets

I'm using paperclip to upload my images, in this instance i would like to use the pdf as an image and enable the user to have the option of downloading it. I upload my images to an S3 bucket.

Currently when trying to render the image it fails to load the given URL

```
<% for i in @timetable %>
  <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:timetable)) %>
<% end %>
```

Whereas the exact same code works if the image type is png or jpeg for example

The HTML generated is

```
<img src="http://ymcagym.s3.amazonaws.com/images/timetables/13/timetable.pdf?1392893849" alt="Timetable">
```

When putting the link in the url it renders but opens in a pdf reader

How would i go about getting it to open as an image? and also having the option to download

The

Thanks

Comment: So i.photo is a pdf, not a png/jpg?

Comment: in this example yes, as soon as i.photo is a png/jpg the image will render fine

Comment: image_tag is just a helper - all it does is generate some html. What html does it generate?  The issue is with `i.photo.url(:timetable)` - what is `i` here?  What happens if call `.photo.url(:timetable)` on an object of this type in the console?

Comment: updated question MaxWilliams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce the file format when specifying your styles, for example:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :timetable => ['100x100#', :jpg],
    ...
  }
```

this should create a preview image of the first page for you on upload. Be sure to run `rake paperclip:refresh` to regenerate your assets.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so if i specify :pdf, will a user be able to view the image? and then download it as a pdf if required?

Comment: The original file will contain the pdf (`photo.url`) and the `:timetable` style will contain a preview image of the first page in jpg format (`photo.url(:timetable)`). Btw, if you wish to preserve the original aspect ratio, just leave the format string empty, i.e. `['', :jpg]` or `[nil, :jpg]`, I am not sure. You can also use png as format if you prefer.

Comment: thats awesome, did not know you could do that, thank you so much